# Spring Exception: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a ResponseEntiy that receives a comment:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save-comment", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> saveComment(@RequestParam("name") String comment, @RequestParam("id") long id) {

    SiteUser user = authController.getUser();

    String cleanedCommentBody = htmlPolicy.sanitize(comment);

    StatusUpdate status = statusUpdateService.getOneById(id);

    Comment createdcomment = new Comment();
    createdcomment.setCommentdate(new Date());
    createdcomment.setCommenttext(cleanedCommentBody);
    createdcomment.setStatusUpdate(status);
    createdcomment.setSiteUser(user);

    commentService.createComment(createdcomment);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The code in my JSP works fine.... it sends the values to my Controller method and the method receives it, process the information and saves the new comment in the database, but after that, showing the same page.... **it gives me the error. But other POST request I have work fine.**

```
http://192.168.160.128:8080/viewonestatus/58 
Exception: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: 
Request method 'POST' not supported
Failed URL: http://192.168.160.128:8080/viewonestatus/58
Exception message: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

The AJAX snippet is that gives an ok code is:

```
.....
<c:url var="saveComment" value="/save-comment" />
.....

function saveComment(text) {
    //alert("El texto es...text " + text);
    editComment(text, "${status.id}", "${saveComment}");
}

function editComment(text, id, actionUrl) {

    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });

    $.ajax({
        'url' : actionUrl,

        data : {
            'name' : text,
            'id' : id
        },

        type : 'POST',

        success : function() {
            alert("Ok");
        },

        error : function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the value of `actionUrl`?

Comment: The problem appears to be that you are not paying attention.  How is it that you believe Failed URL: http://192.168.160.128:8080/viewonestatus/58 matches "/save-comment" ?

Comment: Why is /viewonestatus/58 involved? Sorry, but I do not see what you mean! Can you explain? I promise I will punch myself when I find out :-) The c:url var="saveComment" value="/save-comment" mapps the relation beetween them. I manage to solve it with a regular Post method in the Controller that redirects to /viewonestatus/58... So, i think that there is something I do not understand